# STM32F10x DMA a constant value

Tags: stm32f10x, dma

does anyone know if it's possible to DMA a constant value using the STM32F103? I've scrutinized the datasheet but can't see anything obvious and nothing via Google either. Could do a single word in circular mode of course but it would be nice to avoid the bus access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Just do not increment the source address in memory-to-memory or memory-to-peripheral mode.

*DMA_CCRx->MINC (bit 7)*

Comment: Yes, but will it continually read the value from memory or cache it?

Comment: @CharlieSkilbeck It will read from memory. That's how the architecture works.